# Check if pandas dataframe is subset of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Python Pandas dataframes A, B, with the same columns (obviously with different data). I want to check A is a subset of B, that is, all rows of A are contained in B.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Method [`DataFrame.merge(another_DF)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) merges on the intersection of the columns by default (uses all columns with same names from both DFs) and uses `how='inner'` - so we expect to have the same # of rows after `inner join` (if neither of DFs has duplicates):

```
len(A.merge(B)) == len(A)
```

PS it will NOT work properly if one of DFs have duplicated rows - see below for such cases

Demo:

```
In [128]: A
Out[128]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [129]: B
Out[129]:
   A  B  C
0  4  5  6
1  1  2  3
2  9  8  7

In [130]: len(A.merge(B)) == len(A)
Out[130]: True
```

---

for data sets containing duplicates, we can remove duplicates and use the same method:

```
In [136]: A
Out[136]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  1  2  3

In [137]: B
Out[137]:
   A  B  C
0  4  5  6
1  1  2  3
2  9  8  7
3  4  5  6

In [138]: A.merge(B).drop_duplicates()
Out[138]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
2  4  5  6

In [139]: len(A.merge(B).drop_duplicates()) == len(A.drop_duplicates())
Out[139]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

You also can try:

```
ex = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["banana", "tomato", "apple"],
               "col2": ["cat", "dog", "kangoo"],
               "col3": ["tv", "phone", "ps4"]})
ex2 = ex.iloc[0:2]
ex2.isin(ex).all().all()
```

It returns `True`

If you try to switch some values such as `tv` and `phone` you get a `False` value

```
ex2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["banana", "tomato"],
               "col2": ["cat", "dog"],
               "col3": ["phone", "tv"]})
ex2.isin(ex).all().all()
>> False
```

Comment: Should add the disclaimer, this does not work with null values.

Comment: replace `null` values by some constant value

Comment: That still won't work, as one dataframe may have the constant value *as a value* and the other may be a null value replaced.

Comment: `uuid.uuid4().hex` returns `e3c8a1c39965435690721002632a96e1`

Comment: what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

In the special case where you do not have any `NaN`/ `None` values, you can use `np.in1d` combined with `np.stack` and `np.all`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(40).reshape(10, 4))

res = np.stack([np.in1d(df1.values[i], df2.values) for i in range(df1.shape[0])]).all()
# True
```

This will not deal with duplicates, e.g. 2 identical rows in `df1` may match with 1 row in `df2`. But it is not clear whether this is an issue.