# How does one check if all rows in a dataframe match another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Say you have 2 dataframes with the same columns.

But say dataframe A has 10 rows, and dataframe B has 100 rows, but the 10 rows in dataframe A are in dataframe B. The 10 rows may not be in the same row numbers as dataframe B.

How do we determine that those 10 rows in df A are fully contained in df B?

For example.

Say we have this for df A (only using 1 row)

```
A | B | C
1 | 2 | 3
```

and df B is:

```
A | B | C
2 | 5 | 5
3 | 2 | 7
1 | 2 | 3
5 | 1 | 5
```

How do we check that df A is contained in B? Assume that the rows will always be unique in the sense that there will always be a unique A+B combination

Comment: Can you provide a sample df? It would be really helpful in visualizing...

Comment: unfortunately the data I deal with is confidential but i can provide a small example

Comment: Just redact it all; replace it with dummy data.

Comment: done - gave a short example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is a Dataframe a subset of another:

You can try solving this using merge and then comparison.

> The inner-join of the 2 dataframes would be the same as the smaller dataframe if the second one is a superset for the first.

```
import pandas as pd

# df1 - smaller dataframe, df2 - larger dataframe

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A ': [1], ' B ': [2], ' C': [3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A ': [2, 3, 1, 5], ' B ': [5, 2, 2, 1], ' C': [5, 7, 3, 5]})

df1.merge(df2).shape == df1.shape
```

```
True
```

---

If you have duplicates, then drop duplicates first -

```
df1.merge(df2).drop_duplicates().shape == df1.drop_duplicates().shape
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530918/check-if-pandas-dataframe-is-subset-of-other-dataframe).

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert df2 into a dictionary, and use `isin` to check:

```py
df1.isin({key:value.array for key, value in df2.items()}).all(1).squeeze()
True
```

Another option would be to convert both dataframes to MultiIndexes and use `isin` or `intersection` - I suspect this may be more expensive computationally than the first option:

```py
A = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)

B = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2)

A.isin(B).item()
True

# via intersection
A.intersection(B).empty
Out[73]: True
```